# pythonic way to replace numbers in a string with their unicode character

Tags: python, string, unicode

I am looking for a python code that will take a non-unicode string, such as `"ab <U0054><U0064>"`, and replace it with its unicode equivalent, i.e.: `u"ab \u0054\u0064"` or `u"ab Td"`

Is there a more pythonic way to write it, than this one?

```
def replace_unicode(s):
    while True:
        i = s.find('<U')
        if i == -1:
            break
        s = s.replace(s[i:i+7], unichr(int(s[i+2:i+6], 16)))
    return s
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This one avoids the infinite loop + break and instead uses [`re.sub`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.sub):

```
def replace_unicode(s):
    # helper function which returns the unicode char for a re match object
    def unirepl(m):
        return unichr(int(m.group(1), 16))

    return re.sub(r"<U([0-9a-fA-F]{4})>", unirepl, s)
```

Comment: thanks! exactly what i was looking for. didn't knew i was able to pass functions to `re.sub`

Comment: `\d` doesn't match all hexadecimal digits, you could use `[0-9a-zA-Z]` instead.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian Thanks, I've totally forgotten about that. `[0-9a-fA-F]` should be a better match, though.

Comment: yes. `f` should be used instead `z` here. It was a mistake. I might have written `z` out of habit.

Comment: the pattern should be Unicode to remind that the input and the result are also Unicode